# Translating 'multos labores subierunt'

Tags: vocabulary, sentence-translation

I am trying to translate the following sentence:

> Diu in undis errabant et multos labores subierunt.

I am able to translate the first part as:

> For a long time the ship was wandering in the waves

But I am stuck on the second part. The definitions given are:

- labor, laboris — effort, exertion, labour, work task, hardship, suffering, distress
- subeo [mainly in this context] — go under

I could attempt to translate this as 'and many efforts went under' but that does not fit in with the context.

**How do I translate "multos labores subierunt"?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The relevant meaning of *subeo* in this case is (strangely enough) directly derivable from the parts of the word: *sub + eo* = "under + go" = **undergo**. [Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsubeo) lists this meaning in B.2.c., though many of the other meanings also fit:

> B.2.c. (The figure taken from stooping under a load, under blows, etc.) **To subject one's self to, take upon one's self an evil; to undergo, submit to, sustain, endure, suffer it**

For your example sentence, note that *errabant* is plural and thus cannot refer to a singular ship: a literal translation would be that "they" (i.e. the crew) wandered. The rest is fairly straightforward:

> Long they wandered in the waves, and **they underwent many trials.**